# A List of Characters That Will Break OLAP Cubes

Tags: unicode, pivot-table, mdx, olap, cube

Today I received a curious error in one of the OLAP cube I was working on. When trying to access it from SSAS or from a external connection in Excel, I received an error similar to what is described below:

[image]

> '', hexadecimal value 0x1A, is an invalid character. Line 1, position
>   325042770. (System.Xml)

Not sure why this special character was displayed as a "->" symbol, but after exporting the error message to text I determined this it was the ["SUB" character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024436/what-is-the-unicode-u001a-character-aka-0x1a). Apparently it was a "[invalid character](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d1b6151a-624e-449e-bb88-40c5ac0b010d/issue-hexadecimal-value-0x1a-is-an-invalid-character-line-1-position-270106-systemxml-in?forum=sqlanalysisservices)".

I would love to "[make sure that user hierarchy does not contain any invalid character.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d1b6151a-624e-449e-bb88-40c5ac0b010d/issue-hexadecimal-value-0x1a-is-an-invalid-character-line-1-position-270106-systemxml-in?forum=sqlanalysisservices)", however I don't know what the definition of that is, clearly you can't load the "SUB" character into a cube, however I'm not sure what other characters can or cannot be loaded in.

There are [various claims](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/61cd7bea-6015-4300-ba3e-3623047bf32c/handling-special-character-on-ssas-cube-dimension?forum=sqlanalysisservices) being made about what is and is not allowed in cube dimension names, values, and descriptions. Overall however, when I look around the [documentation seems very sparse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/reserved-keywords-mdx-syntax?view=sql-server-ver15), and there is not mention of the "SUB" character. In there a list of characters somewhere, or some sort of official (or non) documentation on this subject?

Answer (score 1):

If you still suspect that there is an issue with the data of one of the dimension attributes, you can also try to tweak this InvalidXMLCharacters attribute property:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A coworker suggested that I validate all input against XML spec since the cubes are built on top of XML. I think something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28152666/2912011), will cover this character and likely several others. Probably will validate all my input characters [with the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48892895/2912011):

```
System.Xml.XmlConvert.IsXmlChar
```

Still not sure this covers ALL invalid characters in the cube, both for now it's the best I have in lieu of better documentation.