# Javascript : Detect illegal arrows unicode and replace with blank

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8

Illegal Arrow : `escape(strNotes)` : result -> `"%1A"`

This is the illegal Arrow : https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/unicode/U+001A

I am not able to paste the strNotes but strNotes in system is replaced by an illegal arrow looking character which breaks the system.

Proper Arrow : `escape('→')` : results -> `"%u2192"`

But if I use the above `proper arrow`, it works well.

How to detect the Illegals arrow and special characters in Javascript and remove them from String?

Comment: please post `strNotes` value

Comment: If I try to paste that then after saving  it vanishes.  I am posting photo of it.

Comment: `%1A` is a control character https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character. You should first figure out how it got there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024436

Comment: @devio So the notes were a copy paste from some system. Does that mean there are other characters like this, if so how can we replace them by a `blank`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace(/ /, '')`, and replace them all.

Comment: Use something like this ``` let specialChars = "!@#$^&%*()+=-[]\/{}|:<>?,.";

for (let i = 0; i < specialChars.length; i++) {
  stringToReplace = stringToReplace.replace(new RegExp("\\" + specialChars[i], "gi"), "");
}```

Comment: This would have worked if I know what I am replacing, but in my case, I dont know that.

Comment: You can leave only characters str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")

Comment: @NagendraSingh I thought you said the character was \x1A, so you would write `replace(/\x1A/g, '\u2192')` to replace it with a real arrow.

Comment: Yeah actually I ran a loop and included all characters from `https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/unicode/U+001A` and removed all the characters from `0 - 36` after converting each to unicode. and removed it from the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace ASCII characters

```
text.replace(/[^\ -~]+/g, '')
```

-~ is minus tilde - ~

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this, thanks to @devio

```
    String.prototype.toUnicode = function () {
        var uni = [],
            i = this.length;
        while (i--) {
            uni[i] = this.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return "&#" + uni.join(';&#') + ";";
    };

    let setOfIllegalCharacters = new Set();
    for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        setOfIllegalCharacters.add("&#" + i + ";");
    }


        // this iterates through the strNotes string and removes all illegal or bad characters.
        for (let i = 0; i < strNotes.length; i++) {
            if (setOfIllegalCharacters.has(strNotes[i].toUnicode())) {
                strNotes = strNotes.replace(strNotes[i], '');
            }
        }
```