# html string automatically substitutes unicode characters

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, unicode, ejs

I have some product descriptions on my website that for some reason are getting (what I found online) unicode substitutions instead of the value of the string. for example, one of my product desc starts off with `5 inch round window ...`, however, on the website, it is actually showing up `5◆ round window`, and in my logs, I get `5\u001a round window ...`. does anyone know why this could be happening??

note: im using ejs front end framework

Comment: Do you have a `meta` element with a `charset` attribute on your page? It will be `<head><meta charset="HERE"> ... </head>`. You might be using a unicode character that isn't supported by the character set encoding you have selected (or not selected). A common charset encoding is "UTF-8".

Comment: yes, I have this: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in there. thought this would work, but still getting the `5\u001a round window ...` in there

Comment: Read this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type). Is your charset declaration the first meta tag in the head element? It's supposed to be as early in your document as possible, not buried beneath a bunch of link tags, etc.

Comment: @Matt I replaced `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` with `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />` and still the same issue... super strange, not sure why still happening 

Comment: Some [more research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024436/what-is-the-unicode-u001a-character-aka-0x1a) indicates that `\u001a` is a control character that has no character representation. So do you just have a rogue character in your document? Cheer up, use Google :)

Comment: ill have to research more, but basically I am calling the string through ejs, so I am not actually hard coding the string value into the html page, I am calling it from my db. thought that may be an issue, but cant find anything stating so!!